# VS Code dark theme recommendation

Tags: visual-studio-code, dark-theme

I started coding using VS Code. I installed some extensions that I thought would be useful, but I couldn't found any dark theme that looks good for me. For the moment I am using Dark +.

I would like some dark theme, not to colorful, but easy to read.
I already installed the ones recommended on Google, but nothing fits me.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Your question needs more specific requirements. If you have already tested a lot of themes *but nothing fits me*, then how can we answer this? What are your criteria? *not too colorful, but easy to read* are not measurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the ["Winter is coming" theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.winteriscoming) by [John Papa](https://johnpapa.net/) fits you.